# Unable to execute jar with -Dserver.port property

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to run my jar file in a different port using this command

`java -Dserver.port=8082 -jar .\target\demoApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

but im getting error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .port=8082
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /port=8082
```

and when im writing the command like this
`java -jar -Dserver.port=8082 .\target\demoApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

it gives this error

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile .port=8082
```

can you please tell me why this is happening and how to fix this.

Comment: Try quoting it: `java -D"server.port=8082" -jar .\target\demoApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: 1)  Are you using SpringBoot?  Because (AFAIK) `server.port` is a SpringBoot-specific property.  2) How did you create the JAR file?

Comment: Assuming that you have a correctly built SpringBoot JAR file, `java -Dserver.port=8082 -jar .\target\demoApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` is the correct syntax.  The `-D` option **should be** before the `-jar` option; see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#synopsis.

Comment: The first error message *implies* that you actually ran something like this: `java -Dserver. port=8082 -jar .\target\demoApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.  That is, a stray space character in the middle of the `server.port` property name.

Comment: @StephenC yes this is a spring-boot proj, built it using mvn clean install

Comment: In that case, I think my last comment explains your situation.

Comment: i copied the command as it is, as you can see the command doesnt have any space between -Dserver and .port also i tried putting -Dserver.port before the -jar option and have attached the logs.

Comment: @StephenC actually my intellij terminal was set to power shell, because im on windows. Seems to run fine in cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I got the root cause of this issue, actually I was trying the command in the terminal of IntelliJ Idea and it was using power shell. Both the command format seem to run successfully in cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Using intellij idea quoting server.port-8082 in command java -jar -D"server.port=8082"  worked for me.